# Resample/aggregate intervals in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, intervals

For a given data frame containing the active time interval for each item, I would like to compute the number of active items in total over time (likely resampled).

For example, for the data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'active': [
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-04-05 00:00:05')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 01:30:00')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-04-02 02:00:00')),
        pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 01:00:05'))]})
```

on 2021-04-01 00:45:00, there are two active items (`a` and `b`), on 2021-04-03 01:00:00 only one (`a`).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not yet implemented, so use:

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.item,pd.date_range(r.active.left,r.active.right, freq='15Min')) 
                 for r in df.itertuples()])
print (s)
2021-04-01 00:00:00    a
2021-04-01 00:15:00    a
2021-04-01 00:30:00    a
2021-04-01 00:45:00    a
2021-04-01 01:00:00    a
                      ..
2021-04-02 01:15:00    c
2021-04-02 01:30:00    c
2021-04-02 01:45:00    c
2021-04-02 02:00:00    c
2021-04-01 01:00:00    d
Length: 492, dtype: object
```

And then:

```
s = s.groupby(level=0).size()
print (s)
2021-04-01 00:00:00    1
2021-04-01 00:15:00    1
2021-04-01 00:30:00    2
2021-04-01 00:45:00    2
2021-04-01 01:00:00    4
                      ..
2021-04-04 23:00:00    1
2021-04-04 23:15:00    1
2021-04-04 23:30:00    1
2021-04-04 23:45:00    1
2021-04-05 00:00:00    1
Length: 385, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

From [pandas.Interval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html), you can use `in` operator to check if a `pd.Timestamp()` is in `pd.Interval()`. So you can use `apply()` on each row to check if the date to check is in `active` column. Then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to retrieve the desired rows.

```py
date_to_check = '2021-04-01 00:45:00'
df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: pd.Timestamp(date_to_check) in row['active'] , axis=1)]

'''
  item                                      active
0    a           (2021-04-01, 2021-04-05 00:00:05]
1    b  (2021-04-01 00:30:00, 2021-04-01 01:30:00]
'''
```